# How to create Navigation Tabs in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some designI want to create Navigation Tabs in android but In android API 21 deprecated the Navigation.Mode Tabs 
How will we create it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miUWs.jpg)

Comment: use viewpager and viewpager indiactor

Answer (score 0):

Use the support library for navigation tabs.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout